# Why absl flags returns True even when I assign False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, absl-py

Here is the code. I tried to give this parameter 'False' value by using

```
python file.py --add_depth_loss False
```

but it still print "True".... Why is that?

```
from absl import flags, app

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_boolean('add_depth_loss', None, 'sss')
flags.mark_flag_as_required('add_depth_loss')

def main(_):
    print(FLAGS.add_depth_loss)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

Comment: You are reading those values before you called `app.run`.  I suspect you need to move those inside of your `main` function.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I found that the `bool` or `boolean` flag is not used this way. It's actually a "set True" option. If you want to set `False` you need to do `---option=false` instead of `--option False` like other types, otherwise it always return `True`.

Even if you set

```
flags.bool('option', None, 'xxx')
flags.mark_as_required('option')
```

and pass `--option False`, it also returns `True`.

Well, I'm speechless....

Comment: This was helpful, you should mark as the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `python file.py --noadd_depth_loss` instead to set `add_depth_loss` to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding more context from the documentation https://abseil.io/docs/python/guides/flags

*DEFINE_bool or DEFINE_boolean: typically does not take an argument: pass --myflag to set FLAGS.myflag to True, or --nomyflag to set FLAGS.myflag to False. --myflag=true and --myflag=false are also supported, but not recommended.*